# Failure on CSV import into Neo4j 2.2.0-RC01

Tags: neo4j

I'm having some weird issues when using the batch load into Neo4j 2.2.0-RC1. I am trying to import 10 different node sets (for different labels) along with 12 relationship files. The data sets vary in size - some node types have ~200-300k records, some are small (50-100 records). For most node types I have a separate file with a header and separate file with data for each of the sets (the data is generated from the DB and I want to be able to regenerate the dump files without worrying about preparing the :ID columns, describing data types etc.)

I am re-running the import task a number of times (with options --processors 1 --stacktrace) and I keep getting different errors (not a single change in the actual dataset) which makes me think it might be something concurrency-related. Sometimes import simply hangs with a message like this:

```
Nodes
[>:36.75 MB/s------------------------|*PROPERTIES-----------------------------------------|NOD|]   0
```

In most cases, it crashes with an error like below, except the number of nodes that it manages to import fine differs from run to run.

```
[>:27.23 MB/s-------------|*PROPERTIES--------------------------|NO|v:19.62 MB/s---------------]100kImport error: Panic called, so exiting
java.lang.RuntimeException: Panic called, so exiting
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.StageExecution.stillExecuting(StageExecution.java:63)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.anyStillExecuting(ExecutionSupervisor.java:79)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.finishAwareSleep(ExecutionSupervisor.java:102)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisor.supervise(ExecutionSupervisor.java:64)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutionSupervisors.superviseDynamicExecution(ExecutionSupervisors.java:65)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.executeStages(ParallelBatchImporter.java:226)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.ParallelBatchImporter.doImport(ParallelBatchImporter.java:151)
        at org.neo4j.tooling.ImportTool.main(ImportTool.java:263)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Panic called, so exiting
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.AbstractStep.assertHealthy(AbstractStep.java:189)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep.process(ProducerStep.java:77)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProducerStep$1.run(ProducerStep.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nodes for any specific group must be added in sequence before adding nodes for any other group
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.put(EncodingIdMapper.java:137)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.NodeEncoderStep.process(NodeEncoderStep.java:76)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.NodeEncoderStep.process(NodeEncoderStep.java:41)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutorServiceStep$2.call(ExecutorServiceStep.java:96)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ExecutorServiceStep$2.call(ExecutorServiceStep.java:87)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.executor.DynamicTaskExecutor$Processor.run(DynamicTaskExecutor.java:217)
```

I managed to run it successfully once, which, again, seems to imply that some sort of timing issue is at play.

Unfortunately I cannot provide the datasets as they contain confidential data.

The weirdest thing of all is that if I split the load into 2 different sets (the datasets are almost separate subgraphs, they have only 2 relationships in common) then all works fine (so not likely to be data related), but even loading just nodes doesn't work if I put them all into a single command. And because it's not possible to force a load into an existing database, loading it in 2 steps is sadly not an option.

1) Is that a known issue and if so, any ETA on a fix / issue that I could follow?

2) If not, is there any troubleshooting I can do to get to the bottom of it? The messages.log file in the target DB directory contains VERY little output, it would be nice if I could get some more details on what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've spotted the problem. Thanks for reporting/asking. The next release will include this fix. I see an additional set of integration tests for the import tool. I'll provide link to commit once it's in.