# Neo4j shell CSV import issue

Tags: csv, import, neo4j

Neo4j shell import issue

I have an issue with Neo4j shell import. I'm loading data for an initial import to the database. I use about 70 files that contains nodes and relation for the import. But I get an error

```
    Import error: Nodes for any specific group must be added in sequence before adding nodes for any other group
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nodes for any specific group must be added in sequence before adding nodes for any other group
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.cache.idmapping.string.EncodingIdMapper.put(EncodingIdMapper.java:199)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.NodeEncoderStep.process(NodeEncoderStep.java:77)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.NodeEncoderStep.process(NodeEncoderStep.java:43)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProcessorStep$4.run(ProcessorStep.java:120)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.staging.ProcessorStep$4.run(ProcessorStep.java:102)
        at org.neo4j.unsafe.impl.batchimport.executor.DynamicTaskExecutor$Processor.run(DynamicTaskExecutor.java:237)
```

It disappear when I remove some files to the import, but it's not link a  file in particular, then not an format issue.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you use an older version of neo4j? This might be due to a bug that was fixed in 2.2.0. See this similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153901/failure-on-csv-import-into-neo4j-2-2-0-rc01).